# Why my returned value of strchr is ignored?

Tags: c, c-strings, string-literals, function-definition, strchr

I have to make a function, that will code my sentence like this: I want to code all words with an `o`, so for example `I love ice cream` becomes `I **** ice cream`.

But my function ignores the result of `strchr`. And I don't know why.

This is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 1000

char *Shift(char *str, char *let) {
    const char *limits = " ,-;+.";
    char copy[LEN];
    strcpy(copy, str);
    char *p;
    char *ptr;
    ptr = strtok(copy, limits);
    for (int j = 0; ptr != NULL; ptr = strtok(NULL, limits), ++j) {
        int len = 0;
        if (strchr(ptr, let) != NULL) {
            p = strstr(str, ptr);
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ptr); i++) {
                p[i] = "*";
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char *s = Shift("I love my cocktail", "o");
    puts(s);
}
```

Expected output is: `I **** my ********`

but I've got just printed the original string

Comment: Please enable warnings in your compiler and fix all these which are reported. You should be getting a bunch.

Comment: @EugeneSh. oh sorry, I forgot to add my changes, now it works on vs19

Comment: Pass the right type:  "o" -> 'o'

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function `strchr` is declared like

```
char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

that is its second parameter has the type `int` and the expected argument must represent a character. While you are calling the function passing an object of the type `char *` that results in undefined behavior

```
if (strchr(ptr, let) != NULL) {
```

It seems you mean

```
if (strchr(ptr, *let) != NULL) {
```

Also you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior and this code snippet

```
        p = strstr(str, ptr);
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ptr); i++) {
            p[i] = "*";
        }
```

tries to change the string literal passed to the function

```
char *s = Shift("I love my cocktail", "o");
```

And moreover in this statement

```
            p[i] = "*";
```

you are trying to assign a pointer of the type `char *` to a character. At least you should write

```
            p[i] = '*';
```

If you want to change an original string you need to store it in an array and pass to the function the array instead of a string literal. For example

```
char s[] = "I love my cocktail";
puts( Shift( s, "o" ) );
```

Pay attention to that there is no great sense to declare the second parameter as having the type char *. Declare its type as char.

Also the function name `Shift` is confusing. You could name it for example like `Hide` or something else.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * Hide( char *s, char c ) 
{
    const char *delim = " ,-;+.";

    for ( char *p = s += strspn( s, delim ); *p; p += strspn( p, delim ) )
    {
        char *q = p;
        p += strcspn( p, delim );

        char *tmp = q;
        while ( tmp != p && *tmp != c ) ++tmp;

        if ( tmp != p )
        {
            for ( ; q != p; ++q ) *q = '*';
        }

    }

    return s;

}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "I love my cocktail";

    puts(s);

    puts( Hide( s, 'o' ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
I love my cocktail
I **** my ********
```

The for loop

```
for ( ; q != p; ++q ) *q = '*';
```

within the function can be rewritten as a call of `memset`

```
memset( q, '*', p - q );
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, I did not see that.:)

Comment: What do you mean by passing to teh function the array? Like create a char dynamically array?

Comment: @chr See my appended answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- copying the string to a fixed length local array `char copy[LEN]` will cause undefined behavior if the string is longer than `LEN-1`. You should allocate memory from the heap instead.
- you work on a copy of the string to use `strtok` to split the words, but you do not use the correct method to identify the parts of the original string to patch.
- you should pass a character to `strchr()`, not a string.
- patching the string with `p[i] = "*"` does not work: the address of the string literal `"*"` is converted to a `char` and stored into `p[i]`... this conversion is meaningless: you should use `p[i] = '*'` instead.
- attempting to modify a string literal has undefined behavior anyway. You should define a modifiable array in `main` and pass the to `Shift`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *Shift(char *str, char letter) {
    const char *limits = " ,-;+.";
    char *copy = strdup(str);
    char *ptr = strtok(copy, limits);
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        if (strchr(ptr, letter)) {
            while (*ptr != '\0') {
                str[ptr - copy] = '*';
                ptr++;
            }
        }
        ptr = strtok(NULL, limits);
    }
    free(copy);
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char s[] = "I love my cocktail";
    puts(Shift(s, 'o'));
    return 0;
}
```

The above code still has undefined behavior if the memory cannot be allocated. Here is a modified version that operates in place to avoid this problem:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *Shift(char *str, char letter) {
    char *ptr = str;
    while ((ptr = strchr(ptr, letter)) != NULL) {
        char *p = ptr;
        while (p > str && isalpha((unsigned char)p[-1]))
             *--p = '*';
        while (isalpha((unsigned char)*ptr)
            *ptr++ = '*';
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char s[] = "I love my cocktail";
    puts(Shift(s, 'o'));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can also search for multiple characters at a time use `strcspn()`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *Shift(char *str, const char *letters) {
    char *ptr = str;
    while (*(ptr += strcspn(ptr, letters)) != '\0') {
        char *p = str;
        while (p > str && isalpha((unsigned char)p[-1]))
            *--p = '*';
        while (isalpha((unsigned char)*ptr)
            *ptr++ = '*';
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char s[] = "I love my Xtabentun cocktail";
    puts(Shift(s, "oOxX"));
    return 0;
}
```